# My Code is not Printing out but working

Tags: java

```
public class MyThread{

    public MyThread(int m) {
        super();
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int x = 0; x < 201; x++) { 
            System.out.println("Thread Running" + x );       
        } 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread mt = new MyThread(200);
    }
}
```

The code runs, but it is not printing out. It is probably the constructor but the teacher told me to only make a public void run and a main method to allow the code to work.

Also let me know if I'm asking the wrong type of question, I tried looking at the 'How to ask questions' for better question asking.

Comment: You have to start() a thread. You also need to either implement Runnable or extend Thread. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: well I did do the mt.start(); but It kept giving me errors so I deleted it Thanks for the help!

Comment: Take a look to [The Java Tutorials: Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) for a clear explanation on how to use threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Extend `Thread`.

   ```
   public class MyThread extends Thread{
   ```

   Then call `start()` in `main`.

   ```
   mt.start();
   ```
2. Implement `Runnable`.

   ```
   public class MyThread implements Runnable{
   ```

   Then start a new `Thread` passing in your object, and call `start()`.

   ```
   Thread t = new Thread(mt);
   t.start();
   ```

Comment: I personally prefer the second option, because it does not tie the class to be a subclass of `Thread`.

Comment: I was suppose to do both for homework, my teacher said Runnable is the best to use but he wanted us to learn both. Thanks for helping! You got the best answerr! C:

Comment: @Barranka I prefer the second option as well, for the reason you already gave.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing the `implements Runnable` for MyThread. And then you need to `start()` your `mt` thread.

Comment: Silly me! Problem Solved!